# Expected identifier or '(' before NSInteger

Tags: iphone, objective-c, identifier

I'm new to iPhone development and Objective-C, so excuse me if this has already been asked. I've been working on some code, and time after time, this error keeps popping up telling me an expected identifier or '(' before NSInteger is expected.

```
#import "tableTutViewController.h"


@implementation tableTutViewController; 

(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return tutorials.count;
} 

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString * theFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                          pathForResource:@"TPL" ofType:@"plist"];
    tutorials = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:theFile];
    [super viewDidLoad];
} 

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
} 

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4):

If you mean the error is showing for this method definition:

```
(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return tutorials.count;
}
```

then the reason is that you're missing `-` before the first `(NSInteger)`.

All Objective-C methods need to be preceded with either `-` or `+`, indicating whether the method is an "instance method" or a "class method", respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're just missing a dash and a star.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return tutorials.count;
}
```

Comment: It gives me another error, telling me I can't use an object as a parameter to a method.

Comment: Never mind, thanks for the quick replies guys, much appreciated, resolved.